# How to convert a uncommon text format date to date and compare in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two column in a excel and I need to use vba to do these:

One column with text format like these:
column 1: 2015/01/01/09:00:00
there is a / between the date and the time
I need to somehow delete the time and compare this column with another column which is with date format: 1/30/2015

Seem like not that easy, welcome to teach me how to do this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming column A is the first column, and B the second:

```
date1 = CDate(Left(Range("A1").Text, InStrRev(Range("A1").Text, "/") - 1))
If date1 = CDate(Range("B1").Text) Then MsgBox "Match!"
```